# Azure Active Directory Password Policy

Tags: entra-id

I am using AADDS.

I have created a custom FGPP in active directory with a precedence of 1 and applied it to "Domain Users". I changed the minimum length of a password to 14 characters.

This forced multiple accounts to create new passwords.

However...

- Using "portal.office.com" a user only has to have a password length of 8 characters.
- "Default Domain Policy" is showing a minimum of 7 characters.

I am confused. Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

If the user was created in Azure AD (not Azure AD DS), which it sounds like they were as your accessing the office portal with them, then your password length restrictions in AAD DS will not apply. These users will take their minimum length from AAD, and this cannot be changed.

The [docs state this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/password-policy), but a bit vaguely:

> For user accounts created manually in an Azure AD DS managed domain,
> the following additional password settings are also applied from the
> default policy. These settings don't apply to user accounts
> synchronized in from Azure AD, as a user can't update their password
> directly in Azure AD DS.
>
> - Minimum password length (characters): 7
> - Passwords must meet complexity
>   requirements

This is down to the way users that are synced from AAD behave differently to users created directly in AAD DS.